# Экспорт данных из файла Excel в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, datagridview

Нашел код для загрузки данных Excel в таблицу DataGridView:

```
private void завантажитиToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.DefaultExt = "*.xls;*.xlsx";
            ofd.Filter = "Microsoft Excel (*.xls*)|*.xls*";
            ofd.Title = "Выберите документ для загрузки данных";
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Вы не выбрали файл для открытия", "Загрузка данных...", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return;
            }

            String constr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" +
                                ofd.FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';";

            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection con = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(constr);
            con.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable schemaTable = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
            string sheet1 = (string)schemaTable.Rows[0].ItemArray[2];
            string select = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", sheet1);
            System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter ad = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(select, con);
            ad.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
```

Все работает, но к уже готовой таблице DataGridView добавляет еще одну таблицу со смещение данных вправо.